# Create a function which returns the numbers of n digits and a sum of x. Optimization problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

## So here goes nothing...

### Problem summary:

We want to generate all the numbers of three digits where:

- the sum of their digits is equal to 10.
- their digits are in increasing order (the numbers may have two or more equal contiguous digits)

The numbers that fulfill the two above constraints are: 118, 127, 136, 145, 226, 235, 244, 334

Make a function that receives two arguments:

- the sum of digits value
- the desired number of digits for the numbers

The function should output an array with three values: [1,2,3]

1 - the total number of possible numbers

2 - the minimum number

3 - the maximum number

The example given above should be:

```
find_all(10, 3) == [8, 118, 334]
```

If we have only one possible number as a solution, it should output a result like the one below:

```
find_all(27, 3) == [1, 999, 999]
```

#### My first version of code

---

```py
def find_all(sum_dig, digs):
    #is sum_dig even possible with number of digs?
    if sum_dig > digs*9:
        return []

    number_array = []
    #eg generate list of num between 100,1000
    for i in range(10**(digs-1), 10**digs):
        number_sum = 0
        current_number = i
        
        #finding sum of numbers
        for x in range(digs):
            number_sum += current_number%10
            current_number //= 10
        it = iter('1111222233334444555566666777788889999')
        if (number_sum == sum_dig) and all(c in it for c in str(i)):
            number_array.append(i)

    return [len(number_array), number_array[0], number_array[-1]]
```

```py
just an example
print(find_all(10, 3)) returns [8, 118, 334]
```

Part of the program I found somewhere online and currently using it... it won't work well for large numbers...

```py
it = iter('1111222233334444555566666777788889999')
all(c in it for c in str(i))
```

This is basically the same as this, but since I am a noob i don't know which is faster so I decided to use the one above

```py
def is_increasing_order(num, digs):
    for i in range(digs-1, 0, -1):
        if str(num)[i] >= str(num)[i-1]:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

So I will be thankful to any pointers as to what I should do to either speed up my program, or if I have to completely scratch the program then please tell me what special thing I need to use/learn.

If you can edit my code it would be the best because I will learn a lot from the correct code...

Thank you a lot!

## EDIT

I managed to make it run faster by around 30%. Please help me speed it up even more!

```py
def find_all(sum_dig, digs):
    if sum_dig > digs*9:
        return []

    number_array = []

    for i in range(10**(digs-1), 10**digs):
        number_sum = 0
        current_number = i
        last_digit = 99
        is_increasing = True
        for x in range(digs):
            if last_digit<current_number%10:
                is_increasing = False
                break
            last_digit = current_number%10
            number_sum += last_digit
            current_number //= 10
        
        if number_sum == sum_dig and is_increasing:
            number_array.append(i)

    return [len(number_array), number_array[0], number_array[-1]]
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please check out the Code Review site.  Also research how to time your program.

Comment: You're correct that this is a poor algorithm for the task.  If someone made you do it yourself, is that *really* how you would do it?  If not, why is your program written this way?  (That's a guideline, not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: The iter() is quite complicated and i wonder if my is_increasing_order() function is faster... But really I am really stuck.. :(

Comment: ok i see that the code with the is_increasing_order function is actually like 7% faster.. Still looking for suggestions on how to speed my code up greatly

Comment: Why not use the built-in `sorted()` to check whether the number is in sorted order? `def check_sorted: return str(i)==''.join(sorted(str(i)))` runs in less then 1/6th the time of your `is_increasing_order()` function on my machine

Comment: ooh thanks will try that out. Edit: it is faster but the overall code is slower than my updated code i posted above.... still thinking....

Comment: Really, if your code works but you want to improve it, then you should post to [codereview.se] rather than stack overflow

Comment: alright, didn't know about that, thanks

Comment: This is not *really* ready to go to CodeReview.  Do a bit of thinking first, with my previous hint.  Also tag "algorithm" and look up dynamic programming.

Comment: Specifically, if I give you -- a human being with paper & pencil -- `num=6, digs=8`, how are *you* going to do this problem?  Are you *really* going to hand-simulate the loop `    for i in range(10**(digs-1), 10**digs)` -- working through the integers 10,000,000 through 99,999,999 and checking each sum?  Instead, you're going to start by *generating* the correct solutions, checking the digital sums and feasibility as you move along the 8 digits.